# Getting 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function' when using a function inside an if statement?

Tags: php, function, validation, variables, if-statement

Ok, so I just finished off a function for validating the `firstname` field on a form.

This function works correctly on its own.

But since I want to make this function re-usable for more than one website, I added an `if` statement for whether or not to use it. The following code explain this:

Related PHP code:

```
//Specify what form elements need validating:
$validateFirstname = true;

//array to store error messages
$mistakes = array();

if ($validateFirstname=true) {
    //Call first name validation function
    $firstname = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['firstname'])));
    }
    $firstname = validFirstname($firstname);
    if ($firstname === '') {
        $mistakes[] = 'Your first name is either empty or Enter only ALPHABET characters.';
    }
    function validFirstname($firstname) {
        if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $firstname))) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return $firstname;
        }
    }
}
```

So without this `if ($validateFirstname=true)` the code runs fine, but the moment I add it; I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function validFirstname()
```

Are you not able to use functions in `if` statements at all in PHP? I'm fairly new to using them in this way.

Comment: This is not what you want to do: `if ($validateFirstname=true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional functions (functions defined inside the conditions) **must** be defined before they are referred. [Here's what manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, **except** when
>   a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples
>   below.
>
> When a function is defined in a conditional manner such as the two
>   examples shown. Its definition must be processed **prior** to being
>   called.

So if you want to use it that way, you should put it either at the beginning of the if condition or outside the condition.

```
// Either:
if ($validateFirstname==true) {
    function validFirstname($firstname) {}
}

// Or, and I'd rather do it this way, because function is
// created during "compilation" phase
function validFirstname($firstname) {}
if ($validateFirstname==true) {
    // ...
}
```

Also not that function (even if created inside the condition) is pushed to global scope:

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So once code is evaluated it doesn't matter if it's declared inside condition or intentionally in global scope.

Comment: Thanks for this @Vyktor! Makes complete sense now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Functions that are declared in a conditional context (like `if` body), you can only use after their declaration.

```
if ($validateFirstname == true) {
    //Call first name validation function
    function validFirstname($firstname) {
        // function body
    }
    // $firstname initialisation
    $firstname = validFirstname($firstname);
    // ...
}
```

(P.s.: changed `$validateFirstname = true` to `$validateFirstname == true` which should be what you want)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($validateFirstname=true)
```

you are assigning the value "true" to $validateFirstname here
you should use a "==" for comparison e.g

```
 if($validateFirstname==true)
```

that might help your "if" problem